# Fatal error! JSON key 'XYZ' must be set

Tags: json, request, httprequest

I have the follow request header. The JSON looks to be ok

```
POST /exception.php HTTP/1.1
Host: ----
User-Agent: ----
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Content-Length: 68

{
"Key1":"ABC",
"Key2":"DEF",
"xyz":"GHI"
}
```

This is on an internal system we have with no documentation. The error I get back is:

```
Fatal error! JSON key 'xyz' must be set.
```

Which it seems it is! If I delete `xyz` and `Key2` then it says `Key2` must be set. I add `Key2` and that error goes away but it then asks for `xyz` to be set... which it surely is?

Anything I'm missing?

Comment: JSON seems fine. check the API document. And then you may need to submit a bug somewhere.

Comment: No API document :-(